# Download hidden json array in HTML using R

Tags: json, xml, r, httr

I'm trying to scrape data from tranfermrkt using mainly XML + httr package.

```
page.doc <- content(GET("http://www.transfermarkt.es/george-corral/marktwertverlauf/spieler/103889"))
```

After downloading, there is a hidden array named 'series':

```
'series':[{'type':'line','name':'Valor de mercado','data':[{'y':600000,'verein':'CF América','age':21,'mw':'600 miles €','datum_mw':'02/12/2011','x':1322780400000,'marker':{'symbol':'url(http://akacdn.transfermarkt.de/images/wappen/verysmall/3631.png?lm=1403472558)'}},{'y':850000,'verein':'Jaguares de Chiapas','age':21,'mw':'850 miles €','datum_mw':'02/06/2012','x':1338588000000,'marker':{'symbol':'url(http://akacdn.transfermarkt.de/images/wappen/verysmall/4774_1441956822.png?lm=1441956822)'}},{'y':1000000,'verein':'Jaguares de Chiapas','age':22,'mw':'1,00 mill. €','datum_mw':'03/12/2012','x':1354489200000,'marker':{'symbol':'url(http://akacdn.transfermarkt.de/images/wappen/verysmall/4774_1441956822.png?lm=1441956822)'}},{'y':1000000,'verein':'Jaguares de Chiapas','age':22,'mw':'1,00 mill. €','datum_mw':'29/05/2013','x':1369778400000,'marker':{'symbol':'url(http://akacdn.transfermarkt.de/images/wappen/verysmall/4774_1441956822.png?lm=1441956822)'}},{'y':1250000,'verein':'Querétaro FC','age':23,'mw':'1,25 mill. €','datum_mw':'27/12/2013','x':1388098800000,'marker':{'symbol':'url(http://akacdn.transfermarkt.de/images/wappen/verysmall/4961.png?lm=1409989898)'}},{'y':1500000,'verein':'Querétaro FC','age':24,'mw':'1,50 mill. €','datum_mw':'01/09/2014','x':1409522400000,'marker':{'symbol':'url(http://akacdn.transfermarkt.de/images/wappen/verysmall/4961.png?lm=1409989898)'}},{'y':1800000,'verein':'Querétaro FC','age':25,'mw':'1,80 mill. €','datum_mw':'01/10/2015','x':1443650400000,'marker':{'symbol':'url(http://akacdn.transfermarkt.de/images/wappen/verysmall/4961.png?lm=1409989898)'}}]}]
```

Is there a way to download directly? I want to scrape 600+ pages.

Until now, I have tried

```
page.doc.2 <- xpathSApply(page.doc, "//*/div[@class='eight columns']")
page.doc.2 <- xpathSApply(page.doc, "//*/div[@class='eight columns']", xmlAttrs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to download just the JSON data: the JSON array you’re interested in is embedded inside the page’s source code, as part of a script.

You can then use conventional XPath or CSS selectors to find the script elements. However, finding and extracting just the JSON part is harder without a library that evaluates the JavaScript code. A better option would definitely be to use an official API, should one exist.

```
library(rvest) # Better suited for web scraping than httr & xml.
library(rjson)

doc = read_html('http://www.transfermarkt.es/george-corral/marktwertverlauf/spieler/103889')
script = doc %>%
    html_nodes('script') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    grep(pattern = "'series':", value = TRUE)

# Replace JavaScript quotes with JSON quotes
json_content = gsub("'", '"', gsub("^.*'series':", '', script))

# Truncate characters from the end until the result is parseable as valid JSON …

while (nchar(json_content) > 0) {
    json = try(fromJSON(json_content), silent = TRUE)

    if (! inherits(json, 'try-error'))
        break

    json_content = substr(json_content, 1, nchar(json_content) - 1)
}
```

However, there’s no guarantee that the above will always work: it is *JavaScript* after all, not JSON; the two are similar but not every valid JavaScript array is valid JSON.

It could be possible to evaluate the JavaScript fragment instead but that gets *much* more complicated. As a start, take a look at the [V8 interface for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/vignettes/v8_intro.html).

Comment: I think the problem comes with the character the source code has for strings, 'x' instead of "x". I'll be working on that and hopefully let you know the results. Thank you!

Comment: @edufierro Yeah, that’s why the code in my answer is replacing them.